# Calculate average y-value in windows

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Using the mtcars data set (ggplot2) I did

```
library(ggplot2)
plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$qsec)
```

Now I would like to calculate the sd at different points but using windows. So to obtain an sd estimate in the interval from 10 to 15, 15 to 20, 20 to 25 and so on. Afterwars I wanted to display the variance in each window as error bar.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. You calculate the values you desire as new columns in the data frame. Then compute the mean and std. errors for each group, and then plot the means and overlay the errorbars on top.

```
buckets <- c(10,15,20,25,30,35)
mtcars$mpg_bucket <- cut(mtcars$mpg, buckets) #create a new column

#group by bucket and calculate mean qsec
mean_qsec <- tapply(mtcars$qsec, mtcars$mpg_bucket, mean)

#se for bucket = sd/ sqrt(count)
stderr <- tapply(mtcars$qsec, mtcars$mpg_bucket, function(x){sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))})

# Define the top and bottom of the errorbars
limits <- aes(ymax = mean_qsec + stderr, ymin= mean_qsec - stderr)

df <- data.frame( mean_qsec, stderr)
df$buckets <- row.names(df)
ggplot(df, aes(x=buckets, y=mean_qsec)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="gray70") + 
  geom_errorbar(limits,width=0.25)
```

This produces:
[image]